# Inserting comma seperated values into textarea using joomla function

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a custom component,

One of my xml form fields has multiple=true

It gives me the ability to select more than one item from another table via an sql query

However...

I can not work out how to insert it?

```
protected function loadFormData(){

    $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
    $data = $app->getUserState('tourbookings.edit.tour.data', array());

    if(empty($data)){
        $data = $this->getItem();   

        // i added this but no luck
        $data->itinerary = explode(',', $data->itinerary); 

        var_dump($data);

        if($this->getState('tour.id') == 0){
        $data->set('catid', $app->input->getInt('catid',      $app->getUserState('com_tourbookings.tours.filter.category_id')));
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

My var_dump looks like this:

```
object(JObject)#169 (32) { 
["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } 
["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["itinerary"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
}
```

If anyone could help shed light on this i would be grateful :)

note: Joomla provides simple docs on how to create the xml form fields for a custom component but its not so cl;ear how to insert arrays from select lists etc..

My xml that produces a field that lets me select more than one value

```
<field
    name="itinerary"
    type="sql"
    label="Itinerary"
    description="COM_TOURBOOKINGS_TOURS_FIELD_ITINERARY_DESC"
    size="40"
    query="SELECT id AS value, name FROM #__bs_itinerarys"
    key_field="value"
    value_field="name"
    translate="0"
    onList="1"
    onForm="1"
    required="0"
    multiple="1"
    validate=""
    class="input"       
/>
```

cheers
Jonny

Comment: Did you set the user state for the filter you are trying to get in the populateState() model override?  Looks like you are conflating two concepts here; the table filter fields which you set and retrieve using these methods, but the actual filtering should occur in your getListQuery() override in the model.  More code would be helpful.

Comment: @BrianBolli i have just worked out that my addition above allows me to see teh comma seperated values. I was adding 1,2,3 into teh textarea via phpmyadmin. I have tried the prparetable function to see if it will insert my new selections via that but no luck. Are you saying that the populatestate function is where i need to modify the itinerary field to an array in order for my data to save?

Comment: @BrianBolli i have added the xml form field that returns a multiple select list that looks just like the joomla 3 core tags selector.

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure what the end goal is.  Are the CSV part of the edit view form or are they filters for a table list view?

Comment: Maybe i shouldnt have put csv in my heading. Basically that xml produces a multiple sleect form field grabbing data from another table. When i try to save the data it dosent work. If i add the data like so 1,2,3 to phpmyadmin and have that code i added right at the top it displays the data. But then when saving say 1,3 only it still returns all three results. I cant get joomla 3 to save my comma separated data.

Comment: I'm wondering if you would be better served writing a custom field type regardless.  The sql field type is designed more to populate a select field directly with a DB query, and he docs don't mention the multiple as a valid option.  If these are values you want saved to a DB check this link out:  http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63821/discussion-between-jonnypixel-and-brian-bolli).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... can you post the table class for tourbooking?